# Sending response message in a client or bot 'event' in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm having a bit of trouble following the documentation in discord.py for sending messages especially

The following code, which is suppose to print 'Message Deleted' when a message is deleted, crashes the program due to there not being a `send_message` method in the `Bot` object

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    await client.send_message("Message Deleted")
```

Trying simply just '`send`' instead of '`send_message`' does not seem to fix the problem either, Im having trouble differentiating between the two and also knowing which one to use, i'm suspecting that i'm using older syntax than what the current version supports...

Comment: Think logically, even if `Bot` aka `client` had the `send` method, where would it send messages to? What channel? What guild? Where do you see that defined in your `send` call or in `on_message_delete` method?
Instead you should do `await message.channel.send("Message Deleted")`

Comment: right, since I'm not very experienced in Python I think breaking into discord.py as a beginners project might be such a good idea

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
await message.channel.send('Message Deleted')
```

The reason is what Alberto Poljak said, you only use the client's send message if you can supply where the message will be sent to.